# PRTG Interval Datetime for values

Tags: javascript, json, prtg

I'm having a problem with PRTG, I want to bring a real-time data of a specific sensor, however the URL that is generated brings me the data in intervals of 5 minutes, what parameter should I use to be bringing as I comment the value Of the sensor in real time and not intervals?

I leave the following example and the text you send me.

Greetings.

.../api/table.json?content=values&output=json&columns=datetime,value_,coverage&id=10406&noraw=1&usecaption=true

"treesize":576,"values":[{"datetime":"5/2/2017 **5:00:00 PM - 5:05:00** PM","Valor":5439.5000,"Tiempo de inactividad":0.0000,"coverage":"100 %"},{"datetime":"5/2/2017 **5:05:00 PM - 5:10:00** PM","Valor":4791.0000,"Tiempo de inactividad":0.0000,"coverage":"100 %"},{"datetime":"5/2/2017 **5:10:00 PM - 5:15:00 PM**","Valor":5180.4000,"Tiempo de inactividad":0.0000,"coverage":"100 %"},...]

Answer (score 0):

What is the goal you're trying to accomplish? To get real-time results, you would normally not continually pull the results using the API.

What scanning interval are you using?  Perhaps using notifications rather than the API would work better for your goal?

Or using the historical reports with the time period set to "No interval/display raw data", which will give you the entire raw data.

Comment: Please use the comments functionality for detailed questions, as this is not an answer to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following API call can give you historic data with RAW values. These are not grouped since you use avg=0 parameter

`/api/historicdata.xml?id=objectid&avg=0`

There is second call which gives you latest value for specific sensor in case you pull data in real time

`/api/getsensordetails.json?id=sensorid`